# Show $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{x!}{(x + k)!} \leq \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: inequality

In trying to prove something else, I came across what I think is an inequality that holds for all $x > 0$:
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{x!}{(x + k)!} \leq \frac{1}{x} . $$
I haven't been able prove this; everything I've tried has led to a bunch of other inequalities.

Comment: Do you define $(x+k)!$ for non-integer $x$ with the $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I was originally thinking integers, but now that you mention it, I am interested in looking at the inequality in terms of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Based on Angina Seng's answer below, it seems we are making a literal interpretation. Using the gamma function was my first thought, as well. It seems a bit easier if you ignore the fact that $x$ need not be an integer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LHS looks like
$$\frac1{x+1}+\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)}+\frac1{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}+\cdots.$$
It's less than
$$\frac1{x+1}+\frac1{(x+1)^2}+\frac1{(x+1)^3}+\cdots$$
a GP with sum $1/x$ if I'm not mistaken.